# Multiple ListBoxDragDropTargets on a page causes poor performance

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop, listbox, silverlight-toolkit

I'm working on a Silverlight application in which a user needs to be able to drag an item from a single source ListBox and drop it into any of a significant number of target list boxes.  I have this working using ListBoxDragDropTargets, but the performance is quite poor.

Specifically, there are two problems:

1. It uses a large portion of the processor time while a drag is occurring
2. When an item is dragged for the first time, it takes 1-2 seconds for the adorner to appear and for the drag operation to start.

Are these issues endemic to the Silverlight toolkit's drag and drop implementation, or is theres something that can be done to improve the performance?

Comment: @B Sharp, 1st great user name!  2nd did you make any progress on this or get a good answer...?

Comment: Thanks @dFlat.  Sadly, I haven't had any progress on this.  Due to deadline constraints I had to put this on the back-burner and work on implementing some other functionality.  I plan on revisiting this in a couple weeks when some of the other features are complete.